# I want to use Vue 3 without build and without CDN

Tags: vue.js, unity-game-engine, self-hosting

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#download-and-self-host

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#from-cdn-or-without-a-bundler

how do I import vue without CDN?

so what I care about is not having a build step. everything in pure human-legible js.

I found this  https://github.com/maoberlehner/goodbye-webpack-building-vue-applications-without-webpack

I'm going to try and implement it inside unity Embedded browser https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/embedded-browser-55459

the challenge is that my interface cannot load things from the web and it can't be compiled.

Comment: To use Vue as a module from a local installation, you don't want to explicitly include it in a `script` tag in your page. Instead, `import` it in the scripts that use it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. Create `index.html`

`index.html` (using Vue 3 - important!)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Minimalistic Vue JS</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./vue.global.prod.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    {{ message }}
  </div>
</body>
<script>
    var app = Vue.createApp({
      data() {
        return {
          message: "Hello world"
        }
      }
    })
    app.mount("#app")
</script>
</html>
```

2. Download `vue.global.prod.js` from `https://unpkg.com/browse/vue@3.0.11/dist/vue.global.prod.js` and save it along `index.html`
3. Open `index.html` in browser

Works just fine in Chrome or Firefox.

**Notes**

> for the record my code is the repo I linked plus the vue libraries I downloaded and added in the root

*Note: following is related to the [repo linked](https://bitbucket.org/letsdebugit/minimalistic-vue) before question was changed*

The code in repo is written for Vue 2 (just try to open `https://unpkg.com/vue` in the browser). So if you downloaded distros for Vue 3 (for example the link I'm using above) the code from repo will not work

Even if you download Vue 2 version, the code in the repo will not work when opened from file system as it is using native ES6 modules - problem I described in the previous version of my answer:

As described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#other_differences_between_modules_and_standard_scripts) and [here](https://v8.dev/features/modules#module-vs-script) ES6 modules are always loaded with CORS. So just opening the `index.html` in the browser (without using server) will not work (definitely does not work in Chrome). Maybe Unity Embeded Browser has this restrictions weakened (as it's purpose is to be embeded) but without possibility to use desktop browser to develop and test your app, your experience will be terrible. I would reconsider the decision not to use bundler...

**Update 1**
[Building Vue.js Applications Without webpack](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/goodbye-webpack-building-vue-applications-without-webpack/) ([sample project](https://github.com/maoberlehner/goodbye-webpack-building-vue-applications-without-webpack)) will not help you either as it is again using native ES6 modules

Comment: you're right this was coming from the vue version number and nothing else. I don't know why this was being abstracted away by the CDN link, this is anti-user experience.

I have to forge ahead here. I do need to be loading the other js pages with this setup.

Answer (score -2):

To use `Vue` as a module from a local installation, you don't want to explicitly include it in a `script` tag in your page. Instead, import it in the scripts that *use* it. The whole idea of modules is that you can import them which makes explicitly including them in your page obsolete.

In `https://bitbucket.org/letsdebugit/minimalistic-vue/src/master/index.js`, import `Vue`:

```
import * as Vue from "./local/path/to/vue.esm-browser.prod.js";
```

Comment: doesn't work. I don't import vue in index.html, just index.js?

Comment: maybe something to do with forcing vue to load first rather than the rest?